# Gmail Api Python, Nonetype Object Is Not Callable

Tags: python, api, gmail, gmail-api

When I run the code with body() I will get the Nonetype error.

I've tried putting the body into batchDelete() parameter but it causes delegation denied. I have given access to the Scope in cloud.google.com and at this point I'm not sure what I can do next.

```py
#pylint:disable=E1101
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

# The ID of a sample document.
DOCUMENT_ID = '195j9eDD3ccgjQRttHhJPymLJUCOUjs-jmwTrekvdjFE'


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        
        # Retrieve the documents contents from the Docs service.
        
        
        
#This is the code that is causing error. -----------------------------  
     service.users().messages().batchDelete(userId='me').body({'ids':[
        'Listings@yayjobs.net',
        'Listings@yayjobs.net']
        }) 

   #-----------------------------   
    
    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the error/Traceback after running the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line
31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 54, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 46, in main
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Please, check [ask] and post full traceback you get.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: based on [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/batchDelete) `.body` is NOT for selecting elements but it has result after deleting items. And if it deleted with success then `.body` is empty (probably `None`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to notice on the code provided:

1. The call to `service.users().messages().batchDelete` is not indented inside the `try` block. This might have broken when pasting it here, but it is worth mentioning since this is python code.
2. `body` is not a method, therefore calling like `.body(...)` will return an exception. In fact, `body` is the name of the argument of the `batchDelete` method. [Here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#batchDelete) is the specific python client documentation for this method.
3. The field `ids` of the request `body` expects `message ids` rather than email addresses. This is an API specification (unrelated to the python client) documented [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/batchDelete#request-body). There are several methods to retrieve a message id in the Gmail API. For example the method [users.messages.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)
4. Creating the request structure and populating the payload does not mean it  actually make the HTTP request. You must call the method `execute()`. This scenario is documented [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/start.html#execution-and-response).

### Fix suggestion:

```py
...
        service.users().messages().batchDelete(userId='me', body={'ids':[
            '999999f99ff9e99e',
            '9999a99c99c99d99']
            }).execute()
...
```